# Boilerpipe used in Android Causes Error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, boilerpipe

I put 'boilerpipe-1.2.0-android.jar'(https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/issues/detail?id=57),

'nekohtml-1.9.13.jar', 'xerces-2.9.1.jar' into libs folder of my Android Project.

But it caused "Conversion to Dalvik format failed" Error.

So, I did all I found solutions of that error but I couldn't fix it.

I want to use boilerpipe to extract meta data, image Url, text.
Please Help me.

AND If you know article extractor API for android(better than boilerpipe), please let me know